# Delete Stackblitz Project?

Tags: javascript, stackblitz

I took a screenshot.  I want to delete the project that says "Delete this project".  The button no longer appears.  It used to be something that appeared when we hovered over the link to the project (I hovered over it in the screenshot, but the mouse was not captured):

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/1256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the menu bar within the current project you have the icon: "Change privacy settings" - and in the submenu "Project actions" you have "Delete project".

Answer (score 3):

**Now** there seem to be certain places to *delete* the project.. 
*View Profile > kebab menu (3-verticaldots) > delete project*
[image]

 
[image]

Or else you can go to *Project settings > Delete*
[image]

***Basically***, for the people like me who kinda are looking for *' Where is the delete option..?'*